# ¿Cómo declarar este estilo para no repetir 9 veces lo mismo?

Tags: html, css

Tengo una sección en la que habrá 9 pequeños div, cada uno con una imagen y titulos diferentes. Pero sé que como estén posicionados los titulos etc van a ser lo mismo, con lo cual le he dado a ese "pequeño div" una clase, con lo cual los atributos que les de a esa clase pretendo que se apliquen a los 9 div:

```css
.first_section{
 width: 100%;
 height: 1000px;
 background: #E8EFEE;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
.first_subsection{
  width: 85%;
  height: 85%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.first_minidiv{
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('img/london.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="first_section">
        <div class="first_subsection">
            <h5>Destinos favoritos de los viajeros con origen Madrid</h4>
            <div class="first_minidiv">
                <p class="categoria">Diversion en familia</p>
                <div class="minidiv_desc">
                    <h4>Londres <br/>44€</h4>
                    <p class="noches">8 noches</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Hasta aquí bien pero cada vez que cambio la foto en " background-image: url('img/london.jpg');"  obviamente tengo un problema, se sobrescribe la foto y todas acaban con la misma.

He probado a poner `<div class="first_minidiv uno dos tres cuatro cinco seis siete ocho nueve">`
 Aplicando la imagen invididualmente a cada clase por numeros y dejar first_minidiv como está pero quitando el atributo de background-image (no se si me explico) pero también se sobrescribe.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Desde donde estas cambiando el `background-image` individualmente?

Comment: ¿Las imágenes van a cambiar alguna vez de manera dinámica o siempre van a ser la misma con la que cargó el **HTML**?

Comment: @DanielMauricioSánchezÁvila desde el mismo CSS también

Comment: Podrías especificar tu background-image directamente en el elemento del DOM, eso lo solucionaría...

Comment: @PHPMyguel en principio siempre con la misma por qué lo estoy haciendo sólo para cuestiones de aprendizaje. Aunque me gustaría saber como hacerlo de manera dinámica ya que en el futuro imagino que realmente será para lo que me será útil.

Comment: Lo que yo haría sería tener la clase para darles a tus **div** esos estilos generales que necesitan que tengan todos y luego, ponerle a cada uno su propia **id** de esa manera puedes ponerles a cada uno su propia imagen de background. De esa manera ya no metería el background-img en la clase, si no que lo sacaría de ahí y metería el suyo propio en cada **id**.

Comment: Si vas a cambiar solo la imagen de los `divs` desde el `css` crea una clase particular para todos en la que apliques estilos para los `titulos y parrafos` y ya le agregas una clase en particular y a esa le cambias el `background-image` como lo tienes en la clase `.first_minidiv` `.second_minidiv` `.third_minidiv` etc...

Comment: @DanielMauricioSánchezÁvila eso sería crear estilos para cada div, cosa que es poco eficiente y lo que justamente se quiere evitar

Comment: pero si lo va a hacer por css como mas se va a hacer? si fuera desde js sería mucho mas eficiente @PauloUrbanoRivera

Comment: Si fuese con JS podrías montar un bucle for que recorra cada uno de los elementos y un array con la ruta de las imágenes a insertar de tal manera que a cada nueva iteración del bucle salte al siguiente item del array y lo inserte. Pero la pregunta se hace en referencia a HTML y CSS por lo que te queda casi como única opción el ir colocando los background por id para que el elemento quede referenciado únicamente. Aunque sean 100, como comentas.

Comment: se pueden usar ids, inline style=background-image o si va por javscript podes ponerle un data-background=london.jpg y vas cargando las imágenes para cada  div ( util para un efecto unveil o lazy loading)

Comment: Puedes usar un preprocesasdor de css como [sass](https://sass-lang.com/) en la cual te permite crear variablesy bucles de los que carece css

Answer (score 4):

Intenta ponerle un id al div y luego en el css con el id le pones la imagen de fondo

```
.first_minidiv{
        overflow: hidden;
        background-size: cover;        
        background-position: center;
        width: 30%;
        height: 30%;
      }
      #london{
        background-image: url('img/london.jpg');
      }
```